# Asp.Net - how to re size a grid view control within a master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview

I'm using a grid view which contains 7 text boxes and a total of 8 columns in it. When I design it in a plain web form it's displaying normally. But when I add it to the master page the grid view crosses the master page border. I have tried changing the border width of the grid view control but it's not changing. Can anyone please let me know how to come over this issue? I just want to resize the grid view control.

[image]

Comment: not working.. the image which is being displayed has already set to 100% width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put GridView into a Scrollable Panel:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" ScrollBars="Both" Width="100%">

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>

</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine but the text boxes inside the grid view are too lengthy.. how to re size each item template(text box) now..